# How to launch a WAR by restricting the environement to JDK 1.5 with Websphere 7?

Tags: java, deployment, websphere, war, websphere-7

I would like to know if it is possible to launch a war which have to run with the JDK 1.5 (not compliant with JDK 1.6) under Webpshere 7.

Comment: Could you please explain how to create code that works under java 1.5 and is not 1.6 compliant? As far as I know java is backwards compatible.

Comment: Yes I know usually it's compliant, but the war is based on a complicated home made framework, in stand alone mode, we can run the application under the JDK 1.6 when we specify the targeted version to 1.5. But presently we have no choice, we have to find a way to run our application on WS7. Of course, no body know how WS works :). You know, the money, the contracts, the commercials ...

Comment: Again, find what does specifically require your homemade framework? If it checks the java version, call System.setProperty() and pass the simulated version. What else could be?

Comment: Ah, yes why not, but if I change the simulated version from System.setProperty(), it will be for the ALL deployed apllications or just for the war where the method is called.

Comment: Regarding the specifically it's come from embedded jar compiled in jdk 1.5 whereas WS provide its for jdk 1.6, it was the case for the jmx-remote.jar, jmx-ri.jar that I removed. But I know that others problems will come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible/supported to run WebSphere Application Server 7.0 process with any other JDK than the one that is bundled with the product.

Comment: ok thx for your response, but can we specify the java version for a WS's elements like node, server,profile, etc.

Comment: I updated the answer.  No, it is not possible/supported to run any process type with a JDK other than the one bundled with the product.

Comment: I disagree. But I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You provide no details. Again I go back to us. We use JDK 1.5. We run on WAS 7. AND we have no problems working with the database. Granted we do tend to use Hibernate and Data Sources. But still. I don't think what you are trying to do is impossible. UNLESS..you are trying to use 1.6 specific API's for JDBC in 1.5 compiled code. THAT won't work.

Comment: With what do you disagree? thibault's assertion that he needs a non-default JDK, or my assertion that non-default JDKs are unsupported?

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess it looks like I was disagreeing with you. I meant it as I disagreed with thibault. I really think he can do what he wants but just doesn't know how to do it. And he hasn't given specifics so it is hard to help with.

Comment: No worries.  I agree thibault should look to fix or workaround whatever incompatibility exists in his app on JDK 6.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't know where I went. Now it's better for us, we know that our application is not compatible with the IBM JVM (due to the Boolean and boolean management). We have issues too with our JSP, to high (more than 64k, so the JVM 1.6 (SUN) doesn't want compile them). Finally, we have too much issues to resolve to make our application WS7 compliance. Thank you for your help. I had got the response that I hoped.

Comment: this is a bit late, but for whoever reads this in the future. I think I see where thibault is coming from. It seems like they created classes that are designed against interfaces from 1.5 -- ex. java.sql.Connection interface, but when they run on a 6 JDK,  the interfaces loaded have unimplemented methods, thereby causing an exception when run. just to be clear, even if they manage to make the IBM JDK run as 1.5, it won't work. the interfaces in question do not magically lose the new methods defined as of 1.6. they have to remodel their app.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'm confused by your question. JRE's are to be backwards compatible. So the 1.6 JRE within IBM WebSphere Application Server V 7.x.x.x will run Java EE code as far back as Java EE 1 (which I think might be Java 1.2 compliant) and should support Java SE code as far back as 1.1. (Why you'd want to go that far back, I'm not sure....).

There really is no trouble to it. Just compile your code with a 1.5 JDK (that's what we do), or if you want you could compile it with a 1.6 compiler and flag the compiler to use 1.5.

Your code doesn't have to be 1.6 compliant. It just has to be 1.5 compliant and it will run fine. That is the whole point of abstracting and backwards compatibility with the JDK and JRE.

As an example for you, we have an enterprise application that we compile with Maven 2 using Sun/Oracle's 1.5 JDK. We package in several open source project jars, some of which are even as old as 1.3 compliant and/or compiled.

We package all of this up as an EAR using Maven 2 and we deploy it to IBM's WebSphere Application Server (and we run 7.0.0.9). Our code runs just fine. We even have some modules that we do compile with JDK 1.6 to leverage certain functions in 6, but most of the code is compiled as 1.5. And it runs fine.

So I guess I'm confused what you are asking. Could you provide a more concrete example of what you are trying to do? Because from what you have told me, you should be able to run just fine in WAS 7 without compiling at JDK 6.

Comment: regarding the backwards compatible we have go a problem withe JDBC (java.sql from rt.jar). Our application define a data source using classes from java.sql, but beetween jdk 1.5 et jdk 1.6 the signatures of interfaces are different (you can see the class java.sql.Connection). So if we can't compile in JDK 1.6 and if we launch under jdk 1.6 we have SQLException. That why I wanted to know if it was possible to specify a java version for an element of WS7 (server, profile, node, application, etc.)

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing where you are going. java.sql.Connection should not give you any problems AS LONG AS you are using the JDK 1.5 compliant methods. And what is your SQLException? If you could post that with the stack track that would be a LOT more helpful with us solving your problem. Also...if you are in WAS, why not use a Data Source to abstract your DB rather than trying to work with direct JDBC, or did I misunderstand what you are trying to do?